# How to figure out equilibrium and isoclines

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have this question :

> For the dynamical system
> $$\begin{align*}
> \dot{x}&= (2-x-y)x \\[5pt]
> \dot{y}&= (1-3x-4y)y\\[5pt]
> \end{align*}$$
>
> Find all the equilibrium points of the system. Determine the horizontal and vertical isoclines of the system.

So usually I go about just solving them as to set $f(x) =$ RHS and then solve for eq. pts but I'm not sure how to do this. I plugged into a graphing website but would want an explanation / method on how to do this

Thank you:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this kind of problems, what you usually have to do is start finding the nullclines, i.e. the subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ where either $f(x,y) = \dot{x}=0$ or $g(x,y)=\dot{y}=0$. Then, to find the equilibria, if any, you just have to find the intersections between these two sets. Indeed, an equilibrium point is a point where both $\dot{x}=\dot{y}=0$.

In your case, as you've mentioned, you can set $\dot{x} = f(x,y) = (2-x-y)x$ and $\dot{y} = g(x,y) = (1-3x-4y)y$.

We now start finding the zeros of $f(x,y)$, i.e. the points where the vector field is vertical. To do so we first put the parenthesis equal zero and then the remaining part.

So $f(x,y)=0$ if either $2-x-y=0$ or $x=0$. The first set of points  defines the line $y = 2-x$.

Then, you look where the vector field is horizontal, i.e. where $g(x,y)=0$. Here the reasoning is the same, so you get that either $y=-3/4x+1/4$ or $y=0$.

So now that you have found the isoclines (or nullclines to be precise), you can find their intersections to find the equilibria.

We start fixing $x=0$, which makes $f=0$. We see that the only way to have that even $g(0,y)=0$, is to set either $y=0$, getting the first equilibrium $P_1=(0,0)$, or $y=1/4$ so that you get the point $P_2=(0,1/4)$ which lives in the line where $g$ vanishes.

Then we choose the other set where we have seen that $f$ vanishes, i.e. the line $y=2-x$ and see if for some points in the set $\{(x,2-x):x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ the function $g$ vanishes, i.e. if it has non trivial intersection with the points we have found before.

We see that if $x=0$, we get $y=2$ and hence this choice makes both $f=g=0$, and gives the third equilibrium point $P_3=(0,2)$. To conclude, we just need the intersection between the two lines $y=2-x$ and $y=-3/4x+1/4$ which stands at the forth and last equilibrium $P_4 = (7,-5)$.

Comment: thank you very much x